# cannot open source file "stdio.h"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm new to programming with C, I typed #include <stdio.h> but it results in an error that states "cannot open source file "stdio.h". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers". What is the fix to this issue?

I tried changing the IntelliSense mode from ${default} to windows-clang-x64 but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: How did you build your program ?

Comment: Uninstall VSCode, it is not suitable for beginners. Install a different IDE instead, or go without an IDE (a simple text editor plus command line tools).

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/introvideos-cpp and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp and depending on the compiler and OS you're using the relevant subsections.

Comment: I may be kinda useless, but I use "Sublime Text" to write the code, then compiling and run it through the command prompt, with GCC compiler. Installing GCC will instal all the headers and coresponding libraries.

Comment: @Sandrious not useless at all, in fact that is the best way to learn how to compile. Once you understand how to compile your code manually from the command line -- then you can tell and IDE how you want your code compiled. Until then, many new users are just left hoping the IDE configuration is correct. If you don't know what options, optimizations and language standard you need to use, you can't configure an IDE. Building from the command line is the very best way to learn. (and it's a hell of a lot quicker than jacking with IDE projects...)